# Is there a way to force a two different EntitySets to be cast as the same private List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two entity sets that are called Test1s and Test2s.  The entity class for each is Test1 and Test2.
Test1 and Test2 both inherit from a class called BaseEntity.

```
var atest = CurrentContext.Test1s.ToList();
```

This makes a List of Test1 classes

```
var atest = CurrentContext.Test2s.ToList();
```

This makes a List of Test2 classes

Instead of having atest a local variable in the method I want to make atest a private method in the class.  So I am not sure what to cast it as (and declare it as) and how would I cast it back to the appropriate list later on when I need to use it.

Comment: Missing something here. List<Test1> atest = new List<Test1>(CurrentContext.Test1s.ToArray()) ??? Why do you think you need to cast, and why are you persisting your set as a list, that means you have to deal with the set changing underneath it.

Comment: Also if say the set destroyed a member and you still had a reference to that member in your list. (Or vice versa, some poor git has an intermittent Null Reference Exception you curse you for...

Comment: I won't know until runtime whether I need to save Test1s or Test2s (there are actually more entity sets than just 2 there its like 20 or so.)  So instead of having a private List for each one I just want to use one private List.  I don't care if the set changes underneath I just need a snap shot at the time I do that linq statement.  (The linq statements in the real code have a where statement but I left that out for simplicity)

Comment: What you appear to be saying is giving me the shivers. A class that held a List<BaseEntity>? Another option is to look at what you want to do from the list versus the set, Perhaps interfaces at the entity level? As soon as I hear I need to cast, I immediately think inheritance abuse. Hard to say what you should do from here. Food for thought anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figured it out.

You can use this to change the casting of a list.

```
List<A> listOfA = new List<C>().ConvertAll(x => (A)x);
```

Comment: Well yes, and going from say Test1 to BaseEntity is safe, the other way though, is asking for it....